# Joomla URL Re-writing help

Tags: joomla, url-rewriting

How do I remove this from my pages `content/view/19/50/` instead `www.site.com/page-name/sub-page-name/` without plugins.

Can I just modify the .htaccess file but not sure what rules I need to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it the htaccess way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^content/view/19/50/ http://www.site.com/page-name/sub-page-name/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You could also do a regex in .htaccess to match the content ID and menu item ID. I believe the latter number is the menu item ID.